# Laravel + VueJS .slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Вообщем есть приложение Laravel + VueJS на одной странице, точнее на нескольких страницах есть пагинация сделанная таким образом:

```
paginate (equipments) {
  let page = this.page;
  let perPage = this.perPage;
  let from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
  let to = (page * perPage);
  return equipments.slice(from, to);
},
```

Вроде нечего сложного, но в последнее время на этих страницах начало вываливаться вот такая ошибка:`Error in render: "TypeError: equipments.slice is not a function"`

И я не могу найти почему она появляется и как её исправить?
Вот как идёт получения данных:

```
methods: {
    get_equipments_from_server(){
        this.axios.get('/reports/get_rent_equipments').then((response) => {
            this.received_equipments = response.data;
            this.equipments = response.data;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
},
computed: {
    displayedEquipments () {
        return this.paginate(this.equipments);
    }
},
```

Пожалуйста помогите!!

Весь код прикладывать не буду т.к. он очень дольшой и написан не мной поэтому его показывать стыдно.

Возможно нашел в чем проблема, но как её решить так и не понял, вообщем через vue-devtools показывает: `displayedEquipments:"(error during evaluation)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это случается, когда вы используете функцию `slice` для неправильного типа данных. `Slice` работает с массивом, а не с объектом. Скорее всего вы пытаетесь использовать `slice` на объекте

Comment: Ну нет я проверил, я получаю обратно json массив, как мне исправить тогда вот это: `displayedEquipments:"(error during evaluation)"`. Поскольку раз здесь ошибка, тогда понятно почему в pagination отваливается slice, хотя может ошибка и показывает что slice отвалился.

Comment: возможно ты прав вывел в консоль приходящие данные в итоге увидел:`{__ob__: Observer}
0: Object
2: Object
5: Object`
И как это исправить когда у меня в контроллере: `return response()->json($equipments);`

Comment: Вообщем сделал всё просто там где получал объект сделал так `Object.values(response.data)`, теперь работает

Comment: @Moonwolf45 если вам помог мой ответ, то отметьте его решением